# Resilience4j Not Ignoring Exceptions

Tags: java, spring, microservices, circuit-breaker, resilience4j

JobServiceImpl.java:

```
@CircuitBreaker(name = "jobsApiServiceGetAllJobs", fallbackMethod = "getAllJobsFallback")
public ResponseEntity<JobsResponse> getAllJobs() {
    ...
    throw new ApiException();
}

public ResponseEntity<JobsResponse> getAllJobsFallback(Throwable throwable) {
    log.error("Fallback method called");
}
```

application.properties:

```
resilience4j.circuitbreaker.instances.jobsApiServiceGetAllJobs.ignoreExceptions=ccp.shared.platform.exception.ApiException,ccp.shared.platform.exception.BadRequestApiException
```

Whenever `ccp.shared.platform.exception.ApiException` is thrown, the fallback method is called even though I have added it in the `ignoreExceptions` list in the `application.properties` file. I want it to not trigger the fallback method when `ApiException` is thrown. I have tried similar questions on stack overflow and those does not work for me. Am I doing anything wrong?

Answer (score 4):

Seems that the property is defined in the [docs](https://resilience4j.readme.io/docs/circuitbreaker) but actually, it does not work. There is a pull request for that -> [CircuitBreakerConfigurationProperties has no ignoreException property](https://github.com/resilience4j/resilience4j/issues/1586).

You can use the common Spring+java configuration to achieve that in the meantime:

```
@Bean
CircuitBreaker reportingApiCircuitBreaker(CircuitBreakerRegistry registry) {
    CircuitBreakerConfig config = CircuitBreakerConfig.custom()
        .ignoreExceptions(ApiException.class, BadRequestApiException.class)
        .build();

    return registry.circuitBreaker("yourCircuitBreakername", config);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Pls try this way

```
resilience4j.circuitbreaker.instances.jobsApiServiceGetAllJobs.ignoreExceptions[0]=ccp.shared.platform.exception.ApiException
resilience4j.circuitbreaker.instances.jobsApiServiceGetAllJobs.ignoreExceptions[1]=ccp.shared.platform.exception.BadRequestApiException
```